# access element of $* (or $@) by index

Tags: bash

How do I access eleent of $* array (or $@) by index ?
For example, let's take 3-element array and index=1:

```
a=( a b c )
set -- a b c
echo ${a[1]}
b               # good
echo ${*[1]}
bash: ... bad substitution

echo ${@[1]}
bash: ... bad substitution
```

Comment: Similar to [Indexing and modifying Bash parameter array $@](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11379/indexing-and-modifying-bash-parameter-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BUT

you can assign to another array and have fun

```
function test
{
    declare -a v=("$@")
    for a in "${v[@]}"; do echo "'$a'"; done
}

$ test aap noot mies
'aap'
'noot'
'mies'

$ test aap noot mies\ broer
'aap'
'noot'
'mies broer'
```

**Obviously** this allows you to access by index `${v[7]}` since it is just a **regular array**

Answer (score 9):

`$*` and `$@` are not arrays, but rather space-delimited context variables determined at function or script call time.  You can access their elements with `$n`, where n is the position of the argument you want.

```
foo() {
  echo $1
}

foo one two three # => one
foo "one two" three # => one two
```

Comment: Nice clarification about `$*` and `$@` when compared to arrays.

Answer (score 3):

For arguments, you need to shift it like this :

```
while (( "$#" )); do

   # $1 contains the next argument

shift

done
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll rehash [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11379/indexing-and-modifying-bash-parameter-array/11391#11391) here:

---

#### Indirectly use a command line argument

```
argnum=3  # You want to get the 3rd arg
do-something ${!argnum}  # Do something with the 3rd arg
```

Example:

```
argc=$#
for (( argn=1; argn<=argc; argn++)); do
    if [[ ${!argn} == "foo" ]]; then
        echo "Argument $argn of $argc is 'foo'"
    fi
done
```